# Hyper-V ping VM from different physical host

Tags: windows, hyper-v, route, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

Here is the setup, I'd appreciate if someone can tell me why this doesn't work. This illustration should make it easy to understand.

[image]

From 192.168.1.3 how can I get to 10.0.0.5 ?

Wouldn't a route such as the following be enough?

```
route -p add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.2
```

So essentially the idea being that anything on the 10.0.0.0/24 to use gateway 192.168.1.2 which then can get to VM 10.0.0.5

With this setup and route I can't ping the VM, why doesn't this setup work ?

Comment: It isn't enough to simply configure your workstation to use the hyper-v host as a gateway; the hyper-v host needs to route traffic between the two networks for communication to take place. You might be able to do this with the RRAS role if the hyper-v host is a full windows server but I wouldn't really recommend that on a production network.

Comment: @RobMoir why wouldn't you recommend it on a production network ?

Comment: Simplicity rather than complexity is the way to go on a production network. I'd simply have the guests on the same network as the host, using a dedicated pair of NICs for the guest network/vSwitch, and/or I'd use vLANs and routing on the switch if I wanted to maintain a separate virtual network, rather than ask the host to do it.

Comment: @RobMoir Well I'm all for simplicity, would you happen to have a simple tutorial as proof of concept that I could see, that will help me a lot.

Comment: @RobMoir so if I understand you correctly based on my diagram you would put the Hyper-V host, the physical guest, and the VM guest all on the same network (say 192.168.1.0/24).  You would connect the physical guest on one NIC and the VM guest on another NIC on the Hyper-V host.  The VM host would have to be connected through an External Virtual Switch instead of an Internal Virtual Switch. That way they are all on the same network and "talk" to each other.  To then create separation you would use vLans.  Did I get that right?  I apologize it takes a bit of time for me to understand.

Comment: That's correct. I should probably turn this into an answer if I have the time.

Comment: @RobMoir one more question:), what if the Hyper-V host doesn't have an available NIC to be used for the VM guest/switch?  Is it possible to assign a single External Virtual Switch with multiple vLANs?